# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException Error on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-assets

I'm trying sample app. I'm populating listview data from sqlite db. DB stored under assets folder. Log cat shows DB couldn't open. My database name "mydb", contain one Table: "month" and three column: jan, feb and march.

Check My code:

MainActivity.java

```
package test.lin.com.presqlitedb;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ListView lstMonthList;
    private java.util.List<MonthObj> lst_Month_list = new java.util.ArrayList<MonthObj>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        lstMonthList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        lst_Month_list = dbHelper.getMonth();

        lstMonthList.setAdapter(new LAdapter());

    }


    public class LAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lst_Month_list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lst_Month_list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ViewHolder holder;
            final int pos;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            pos = position;
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtJan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.txtFeb = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.txtMarch = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);


                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.txtJan.setText(lst_Month_list.get(position).getJan());
            holder.txtFeb.setText(lst_Month_list.get(position).getFeb());
            holder.txtMarch.setText(lst_Month_list.get(position).getMarch());


            return convertView;
        }


        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtJan;
            TextView txtFeb;
            TextView txtMarch;

        }
    }


}
```

DBHelper.java

```
package test.lin.com.presqlitedb;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    public static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb/databases/";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private static String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "month";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final int ver = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context context;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        if (checkDataBase()) {
            openDataBase();
            Log.i("run", "open db");
        } else {
            try {
                copyDatase();
                openDataBase();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }

        }
    }

    private void copyDatase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        Log.i("run", "copy successful");

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLiteException {
        // Open the database
       db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        boolean exist = false;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.i("db log", "database does't exist");
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            exist = true;
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return exist;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {

            this.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatase();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public java.util.List<MonthObj> getMonth() {
        java.util.List<MonthObj> lst_month = new java.util.ArrayList<MonthObj>();
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            String sql = "select * from month";
            c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                    MonthObj obj = new MonthObj();
                    obj.setJan(c.getString(0));
                    obj.setFeb(c.getString(1));
                    obj.setMarch(c.getString(2));

                    lst_month.add(obj);
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.toString();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return lst_month;
    }



}
```

MonthObj.java

```
package test.lin.com.presqlitedb;


public class MonthObj {
    private String jan, feb, march;


    public String getJan() {
        return jan;
    }

    public void setJan(String jan) {
        this.jan = jan;
    }

    public String getFeb() {
        return feb;
    }

    public void setFeb(String feb) {
        this.feb = feb;
    }

    public String getMarch() {
        return march;
    }

    public void setMarch(String march) {
        this.march = march;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
01-25 17:00:27.305    5811-5811/? E/SQLiteLog? (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-25 17:00:27.305    5811-5811/? E/SQLiteLog? (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb;/databases/mydb) -
01-25 17:00:27.315    5811-5811/? E/SQLiteDatabase? Failed to open database '/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb;/databases/mydb'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
            at test.lin.com.presqlitedb.DBHelper.checkDataBase(DBHelper.java:82)
            at test.lin.com.presqlitedb.DBHelper.<init>(DBHelper.java:34)
            at test.lin.com.presqlitedb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.lin.com.presqlitedb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My complete code download link

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjmzwwiybs4vvm8/presqlitedb.rar?dl=0

Comment: your database path contains a semicolon  '/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb;/databases/mydb'. Not sure it  is  a good idea ?

Comment: @mpromonet I have updated code. I removed semicolon but shows the same errors db couldn't open.

Comment: Did you have permission to access this file /data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb/databases/mydb ?

Comment: @mpromonet pls check my AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo `DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb;/databases/"`. Remove semicolon between `presqlitedb;/databases/`

Comment: Is it still "Failed to open database '/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb;/databases/mydb'"?

Comment: Yes, still "E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb/databases/mydb'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database".

Comment: Hm, does really exist in your device/simulator under  /data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb/databases/ directory ?

Comment: In addition, why do you use `DATABASE_PATH`? Yor DB is saved under data/... by default

Comment: pls check my completed code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjmzwwiybs4vvm8/presqlitedb.rar?dl=0

Comment: I used to make db path to save under "/data/data/test.lin.com.presqlitedb/databases/". Is it saved under my package without using DB_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problems by using SQLiteAssetsHelper Library.